# Authorization_RequestDenied. Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have to update a custom attribute for a user upon completing registration on web app via an Api.
Api has the logic to construct the request using GraphServiceClient and update. When I ran the code there is an exception thrown

```
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Inner error:
   AdditionalData:
   date: 2021-07-27T17:16:26
   request-id:  xxxx-xx-xxxx-xx
   client-request-id:  xxxx-xx-xxxx-xx
ClientRequestId: xxxx-xx-xxxx-xx
```

This is how the code look like pretty standard

```
 var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
   {  helper.GetName(configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId"),"Id"), Id } 
 };

await graphClient
        .Users[userId]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(new User { AdditionalData = additionalData });
```

Graph Api Configuration in Startup class looks like

```
public static IServiceCollection AddGraphComponent(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId"))
        .WithTenantId(configuration.GetValue<string>("TenantId"))
        .WithClientSecret(configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret"))
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
        
    services.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(sp =>
    {
        return new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
    });

    return services;
}
```

Based on the documentation provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) Client Credential provider seems to be the correct provider for my scenario as described in the begining. WebApp -> **X-Api** -> AzureB2C

This is how the X-Api | API Permissions look like.

[image]

Here is the b2c-extension app | API Permissions look like
[image]

Overall it seems like permissions issue not sure what permissions need to be added.

Comment: As seen in the screenshot, read/write operations require admin consent that has not been granter. Please retry your operation after granting admin consent.

Comment: Once I granted permission it did work. Please add your comment as answer and briefly elaborate on admin consent, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're performing Graph API operations in context of an application (and not as a user) or in other words the permissions are `Application Permission` and not `Delegated Permission` and the administrator has not given consent to perform those operations. It is required for an administrator to give tenant-wide consent for application permissions. Once an administrator gives the consent, the error will not come.

To learn more about delegated and application permissions, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#delegated-and-application-permissions.